# EXCEL: When I copy and past from one sheet to another it only pastes blanks

Tags: excel

When I am copying text from one tab to another in the same Excel document it is just pasting blanks.

I can paste into other tabs fine, just not the one I want.

I am doing this with a simple Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V

I have:

- Used XLCleaner
- Pasted as plain values
- Pasted into a new tab then copied from there
- Pasted into a new workbook and copied from there

It still pastes blank cells into my source tab

Comment: Are you copying the data using script or just simple Ctrl+C?

Comment: Perhaps this question is more suitable for https://superuser.com/ This doesn't seem to be about programming.

Comment: @newacc2240 simple Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V

Comment: Perhaps you are copying a formula and the formula is evaluating to blank? Just a guess.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Just plain text

Comment: Only other things I can think of is maybe data validation preventing those cells from changing to what you're trying to paste, or possibly formatting or conditional formatting which is formatting the font color as the same background color, making it appear as if the cells are blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a table being "Split" into two parts with separate filters.

I had to redefine the table boundary to include all columns.

Then I could paste correctly.